# run Java Web Start applications in non admin user accounts

Tags: java, windows, jnlp, admin-rights

I have a java web start applications that perfectly works on my pc. The problem is that this app needs to be run on machines where the user does not have admin rights. For linux everything works fine even without sudo rights, but on windows I keep getting errors like this:

```
JNLPException[category: System Configuration : Exception: null : LaunchDesc: null ]
```

Moreover while I tested and make everything work on the 3 test PCs, every time I use another PC I get a new error like

```
JARSigningException
```

or

```
InvocationTargetException - Can't load library: \\Ubz01fst\Profs\User\xxx\swt-win32-3738.dll
```

The documentation is not that much, the debug is difficult on JNLPs. Do you think that it is my problem or as I guess the library is not stable and well defined for all the platforms and the architectures?

Comment: Have you validated the JNLP(s) with [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/)?  How is the DLL deployed to the client?

Comment: It is deployed automatically from the SWT libraries... I am sure that all the jars are signed!

Comment: *"I am sure that all the jars are signed!"*  Note that is not an answer to ***Have you validated the JNLP(s) with JaNeLA?***

Comment: Yes, sorry I run it and it is correct. There was a little problem that i solved now, but the problems still remains.

Comment: Did you uninstall the app. after fixing the 'little problem'?  JWS updates archives well, but it is not so good at updating the JNLP.

Comment: Yes, I automatically deploy the application with an ant script, and I also deleted it from the cache of java.
anyway the little problem was just to switch these two lines:
  <extension href='swt.jnlp' />
      <jar href='setup.jar' main='true' />

and this cannot be the cause of all since I copied this from a sample working application.